# How to rename a complicated formula?

Tags: r

Suppose I have a formula `y~x1+x2+I( (x1==x2)*x3 )` and estimate an linear model

```
summary(lm(y~x1+x2+I( (x1==x2)*x3 ), data=some_data ))
Coefficients:
                   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)          3.6027     1.6069   2.242   0.0662 .
x1                   1.8685     1.9769   0.945   0.3811  
x2                   2.6041     2.0286   1.284   0.2466  
I((x1 == x2) * x3)   0.5666     1.5456   0.367   0.7265
```

Beside creating a new 'data.frame', is there any methods to modify the formula so that the summary table would become

```
Coefficients:
                   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)          3.6027     1.6069   2.242   0.0662 .
x1                   1.8685     1.9769   0.945   0.3811  
x2                   2.6041     2.0286   1.284   0.2466  
some_name            0.5666     1.5456   0.367   0.7265
```

Comment: The name is not stored in the `formula` element but that in the `coefficients`. You might be able to use something like: `rownames(summary_object_name$coefficents)[4] <- "some_name"` but unfortunately you provided no data with which to test this theory. (You would, of course, begin by creating such an object.)

Comment: This is not a bad question, but using a simple built-in example to illustrate your point, like `summary(lm(Sepal.Length ~ I(1:150), data=iris))` would have been handy.

Comment: Also: Are you aware that using I() to represent your interactions will produce very misleading statistical results?

Comment: @IShouldBuyABoat - I'm presuming (and it's a big presumption) that OP understands the difference between `x1 * x2` and `I(x1 * x2)` in an `lm` formula as they mention about 'creating a new data.frame' with a newly named variable.

Answer (score 5):

Using `within` you could hack something up.

Instead of:

```
summary(lm(Sepal.Length ~ I(Sepal.Width * Petal.Length), data=iris))

#...
#(Intercept)                   4.252934   0.069396   61.28   <2e-16 ***
#I(Sepal.Width * Petal.Length) 0.142483   0.005632   25.30   <2e-16 ***
#...
```

You can use:

```
summary(lm(Sepal.Length ~ newvar, data=
         within(iris, newvar <- Sepal.Width * Petal.Length))) 

#...
#(Intercept) 4.252934   0.069396   61.28   <2e-16 ***
#newvar      0.142483   0.005632   25.30   <2e-16 ***
#...
```