# Using the subset argument with R's t.test command

Tags: r

I'd like to select all but the 646 row of a data frame by using the subset argument of R's t.test command. I tried:

```
require(mosaic)
require(Sleuth3)

t.test(Dioxin~Veteran,data=case0302,var.equal=TRUE,alternative="less",
       subset=case0302[-646,])
```

But that didn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to specify a vector of which cases to drop, like:

```
test <- data.frame(x=rnorm(100),y=rep(1:2,each=50))
t.test(x ~ y, data=test, subset=-40)
```

So in your case it should be:

```
t.test(Dioxin~Veteran,data=case0302,var.equal=TRUE,alternative="less",
   subset=-646)
```

As @flodel notes, more info on the `subset=` argument is available in `?model.frame`:

```
  subset: a specification of the rows to be used: defaults to all rows.
          This can be any valid indexing vector (see ‘[.data.frame’)
          for the rows of ‘data’ or if that is not supplied, a data
          frame made up of the variables used in ‘formula’.
```

Comment: Yes. I tracked down where `subset` is used, and it is passed down to a call to the `model.frame` function. `?model.frame` has a better documentation regarding that `subset` argument.

Comment: Also, what the `?t.test` doc fails to capture is that the argument  is indirectly optional. If missing, the default value for `model.frame()` will be used. So you can also do: `t.test(Dioxin~Veteran, data=case0302[-646, ], var.equal=TRUE, alternative="less")`

Comment: @flodel - yeah, you can pass all sorts of changes to the `data=` argument to get around issues - e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/22602005/496803